# Why is the array undefined even though I pushed a value in it?

Tags: reactjs

I have this function type() where I define an array texts and I add some values to it and then I set the local texts array to the state array, so it'll be accessible for other functions as well.

```
var texts = [];
texts.push("Hello", 20, 20)
this.setState({texts: texts})
```

And this is the state:

```
state ={
        texts:[]
      }
```

I check with the alert() what's the index of 0 of the array to see if it's working, however it says it's undefined:

```
alert(this.state.texts[0])
```

This is my whole function:

```
type()
    {
        
        var canvas = document.getElementById('board'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            font = '20px sans-serif',
            hasInput = false;
        var sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
        var sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
        canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
        canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));
        
        var texts = [];
        texts.push("Hello", 20, 20)
        this.setState({texts: texts})
        alert(this.state.texts[0])
        ctx.font = font
        ctx.fillText("rrwerwewewrewrwerwe", 50, 50)

        canvas.onclick = function(e) {
            if (hasInput) return;
            addInput(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        }


        //Function to dynamically add an input box: 
        function addInput(x, y) {

            var input = document.createElement('input');

            input.type = 'text';
            input.style.position = 'fixed';
            input.style.left = (x - 4) + 'px';
            input.style.top = (y - 4) + 'px';

            input.onkeydown = handleEnter;

            document.body.appendChild(input);

            input.focus();

            hasInput = true;
        }

        //Key handler for input box:
        function handleEnter(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                addText(this.value, parseInt(this.style.left, 10), parseInt(this.style.top, 10));
                document.body.removeChild(this);
                hasInput = false;
            }
        }

        //Draw the text onto canvas:
        function addText(text, x, y) {

            ctx.position = 'absolute';
            ctx.font = font;
            ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: @MuratKaragöz actually it still doesn't work, idk why